# How to make web parts available to groups or users?

Tags: web-part

Is there a way to make certain web parts visible to selected users or groups?

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52302/displaying-some-webpart-controls-only-to-some-user-groups or http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62880/can-we-avoid-clunky-hiding-of-webparts

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just fix the target Audiences. follow the method.

First of All make sure that You enabled option of Audience targeting settings.

If Not then Follow this steps to enable it Select the list or library that contains the item that you want to target. On the list toolbar, click Settings, and then click List Settings or Document Library Settings. Under General Settings, click Audience targeting settings. Select the Enable audience targeting check box.

1.Select the list or library that contains the item that you want to target.
2.On the list toolbar, click Settings, and then click List Settings or Document Library Settings.
3.Under General Settings, click Audience targeting settings.
4.Select the Enable audience targeting check box.

After this check for the option of Target Audiences in your web part .

http://www.share pointboost.com/blog/how-to-configure-the-target-audience-for-a-web-part-in-share point-2010-sites/

Thanks.

Comment: I have come across another problem... I do not have the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure” feature options mentioned in the guide.. Am I totally missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just fix the target Audiences. follow the method.

First of All make sure that You enabled option of Audience targeting settings.

If Not then Follow this steps to enable it Select the list or library that contains the item that you want to target. On the list toolbar, click Settings, and then click List Settings or Document Library Settings. Under General Settings, click Audience targeting settings. Select the Enable audience targeting check box.

1.Select the list or library that contains the item that you want to target.
2.On the list toolbar, click Settings, and then click List Settings or Document Library Settings.
3.Under General Settings, click Audience targeting settings.
4.Select the Enable audience targeting check box.

After this check for the option of Target Audiences in your web part .

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Prasath,Thank you for your reply.
However I do not have the Audience targeting settings option when i open the list settings..... Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Did you login as admin user?

Comment: I have Edited my post above posting the sutable link.

Comment: @ Prasath - Yep.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not see any link...

Comment: I think I have worked out the problem... I am running Sharepoint 2010 Foundation.. This feature does not seem to be available on the Foundation version... Is there any work around for this? Any help would be most appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Contents > select the web parts settings

Under the Permission and Management select Permissions for this list.

If Inheriting is enabled, select Stop inheriting in the ribbon. Otherwise select Grant Permission.

Then enter the permissions to the users/groups.